# Error de campo auto_increment

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos en Workbench con una tabla llamada `cam_estudio`. Esa tabla tiene los siguientes campos:

```
pk_estudio, estudio, director
```

Tengo como clave principal el campo `estudio` porque necesito que esa sea la clave principal.

Mi problema es que cuando inserto los estudios, se insertan de la siguiente manera:

```
pk_estudio      estudio      director
======================================
    0            65A9        Usuario1
    0            66A1        Usuario2
```

Entonces, cuando voy a poner el campo `pk_estudio` como `auto_increment` me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
ERROR 1075: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Necesito que el campo `estudio` sea la clave principal. ¿Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes borrar la tabla y volver a crearla indicando el campo `pk_estudio` como clave primaria:

```
DROP TABLE cam_estudio;

CREATE TABLE cam_estudio (pk_estudio INT AUTO_INCREMENT, ..., PRIMARY KEY (pk_estudio));
```

Donde `...` son el resto de campos.